# Docker Desktop for Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am trying to run Docker desktop on my windows 10 Pro 64 bit machine with below build specifications and setup details,

- Edition -- Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit
- Version -- 1903
- OS Build -- 18362.657
- CPU -- Intel i7
- Hyper-V Status -- Enabled and i can see all services are running fine.

I have installed Docker Desktop version 2.2.0.3 (42716). I am running this as a administrator and during start it throws me the below error.

- [12:59:40.968][HyperV][Info] Creating VM DockerDesktopVM...
- [12:59:44.416][HyperV][Error] Unable to create Hyper-V VM: Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualizationException: 
  Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object on computer 'DESKTOP-1SOMU3A' because the object was not found. The object might have been deleted, 
  or you might not have permission to perform the task. Verify that the Virtual Machine Management service on the computer is running. 
  If the service is running, try to perform the task again by using Run as Administrator. ---> Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.ObjectNotFoundException: 
  Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object on computer 'DESKTOP-1SOMU3A' because the object was not found. 
  The object might have been deleted, or you might not have permission to perform the task. Verify that the Virtual Machine Management service on the computer is running. 
  If the service is running, try to perform the task again by using Run as Administrator.
  at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.HostComputerSystemView.GetPrimordialResourcePool(VMDeviceSettingType deviceType)
  at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.HostComputerSystemView.GetSettingCapabilities(VMDeviceSettingType deviceType, SettingsDefineCapabilities capability)
  at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMScsiController.CreateTemplateScsiController(VirtualMachine parentVirtualMachine)
  at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.NewVM.ConfigureVirtualMachine(VirtualMachine vm, IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)
  at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.NewVM.CreateObjects(IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)

  - --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I have searched for similar issues and have done the below so far without any success.

1. Uninstall and re-install Docker Desktop (with system reboots)
2. Turn ON and OFF Hyper-V in app features (with system reboots)
3. Changed my system name to avoid any special characters(although looking at the
   error message it is not reflecting the changed system name).

Not sure what could be the issue.Please provide guidance .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is still an [open issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2110) on Docker for Windows. As suggested in the [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2110#issuecomment-517684264) and [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee5b1d6b-09e2-49f3-a52c-820aafc316f9/hyperv-doesnt-work-after-upgrade-to-windows-10-1809?forum=win10itprovirt) you can try:

1. Open *Window Security*
2. Open *App & Browser control*
3. Click *Exploit protection settings* at the bottom
4. Switch to *Program settings* tab
5. Locate `C:\WINDOWS\System32\vmcompute.exe` in the list and expand it
6. Click *Edit*
7. Scroll down to *Code flow guard (CFG)* and uncheck *Override system settings*
8. Start `vmcompute` from PowerShell: `net start vmcompute`

It might be useful to go through the issue because you can find other potential solutions, e.g. [having your hostname and netbiosname matched](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2110#issuecomment-449957618).

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling Docker toolbox. I was having similar problems with Docker desktop for windows. I had previously installed docker toolbox after uninstalling docker toolbox, docker desktop for windows ran correctly.