# Docker Destop for windows in not starting

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

when I am starting Docker either from Docker Desktop icon or from "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe" I get an error that "windows cannot find 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe. Make sure you have typed the name correctly and try again '. I am stuck, is there anything I can do to fix this?

I tried the solutions mentioned in these two SO threads, but nothing worked for me:
[How do we start the daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169435/how-do-we-start-the-daemon)
[Docker Desktop for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60652917/docker-desktop-for-windows)

Comment: Double-clicking on Docker Desktop.exe gives that error as well?

Comment: yes, double clicking on Docker Desktop.exe is also giving the same error

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/q/589030/134834

Comment: Thanks @J.ScottElblein the link you shared actually helped and now my issue is resolved. Kindly repost your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.